# Shift+F10 Function in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, hotkeys

Please help me figure out for <kbd>Shift+F10</kbd> in VB.NET, <kbd>Escape</kbd> and <kbd>F1</kbd> work but <kbd>Shift+F10</kbd> doesn’t work.

Here’s my code:

```vb
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message, ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean
        Select Case keyData
            Case Keys.Escape
                Me.Dispose()
            Case Keys.F1
                MsgBox("You have pressed F1")
            Case Keys.ShiftKey = Keys.F10
                MsgBox("You have pressed Shift+F10")
            Case Else
                Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
        End Select
    
        Return True
End Function
```

Comment: Think you might want to check your logic.  Case Keys.ShiftKey = Keys.F10 would be false.   Could you maybe update your question with how you're using this method but gut feeling is you want to be doing something with the Modifiers property

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```vb
Case Keys.F10 + Keys.Shift
    MsgBox("You have pressed Shift+F10")
```

Result:

[image]